# difiiculty pandas csv output

Tags: pandas, transpose, quoting

I wrote following codes to transpose the datafile containing digit as well as alphabets:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
    def step2(file1,file2):
    source=pd.read_csv(file1,header=None,engine='python')
    dest=source.transpose()
    dest.to_csv(file2,sep="\t",header=None, index=None,quoting=3)
```

Now invariably it yields doublequote in output file, I read the pandas documentation and used even option like `doublequotes=None`, but still yield quotes. The document also mentions that in order to set `quoting=None`, code should contain some escape character. I tried setting `\n` as escaping character then it does escape the quotes but add delimited character after each elements. 
How to remove doblequote from pandas csv output?
Following is the input

```
AU AA GG CC 00 AA TT
```

and following is the output after setting `doublequotes=False` and removing the option of `quoting=3` from above code

```
AU
AA
GG
CC
0
AA
TT
```

I cant explain the behaviour of the code, it changed 00 to 0. I am seeking guidance and one more interesting thing about this output is: when I use following file format:

```
AU AA GG CC 00 AA
AK AA GG CC AA 00
```

the above codes seems to be working fine as expected:

```
AU AK
AA AA
GG GG
CC CC
00 AA
AA 00
```

Can anyone guide me as to why I am getting different output when using a single row?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `doublequote=False`? Also can you post your desired output as you changed `quoting` from the default of `None` to `3`

Comment: And what is your current input ?

Comment: What version of python are you using ?

Comment: Python 3.4.3 and Anaconda 2.3.0

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that it's interpreted the `00` as a numeric value:

```
In [364]:
import pandas as pd
import io
t="""AU AA GG CC 00 AA TT"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),header=None,engine='python', sep=' ')
df = df.transpose()
df

Out[364]:
    0
0  AU
1  AA
2  GG
3  CC
4   0
5  AA
6  TT
```

For multiple lines it works as expected:

```
In [365]:
t="""AU AA GG CC 00 AA
AK AA GG CC AA 00"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),header=None,engine='python', sep=' ')
df = df.transpose()
df

Out[365]:
    0   1
0  AU  AK
1  AA  AA
2  GG  GG
3  CC  CC
4  00  AA
5  AA  00
```

So I think the above is a bug perhaps.

If you changed the engine to the default and specified the `dtype` then it will work:

```
In [373]:
t="""AU AA GG CC 00 AA"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t),header=None, sep=' ', dtype=str)
df.T

Out[373]:
    0
0  AU
1  AA
2  GG
3  CC
4  00
5  AA
```